# Concise way to select the first record before a date in pandas DataFrame with datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Consider this example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame([
    {'d': datetime(2000,1,1), 'v': 'a'}, 
    {'d': datetime(2000,1,2), 'v': 'b'},  
    {'d': datetime(2000,1,4), 'v': 'c'}, 
    {'d': datetime(2000,1,5), 'v': 'd'}, 
    {'d': datetime(2000,1,7), 'v': 'e'}
])

print(df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(datetime(2000, 1, 3), method='pad')])
```

Is this the most concise and efficient way to locate the first record that has a datetime index before the given datetime?

It throws a `KeyError` when given a time before the start of the index, which is fine although a solution that would avoid having to catch the exception, and which is otherwise equally fast (and hopefully a lot more readable), would be preferable.

I had expected something like this to work:

```
print(df.get_row(datetime(2000, 1, 3), method='pad'))  # get the row before the date
print(df.get_row(datetime(1999, 1, 3), method='pad'))  # get None
```

Of course a function like that is simple to add, given the line of code above, but I was surprised by being unable to find an existing method, and hoping to find one here.

Answer (score 0):

You could filter for all records before the threshold and then call `.tail(1)` to get the last of those. This assumes the input is sorted of course.

```
df[df['d'] < datetime(2000, 1, 3)].tail(1)
```

If your data is in unsorted order:

```
df[df['d'] < datetime(2000, 1, 3)].sort_values('d').tail(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; in my case, the index is sorted (it's a clean time series), but although your code is shorter and arguably a bit easier to understand, I don't think it will be very efficient for large time series, as it will actually need to process the entire series and create a duplicate, just to get the tail.

Comment: The loop is internal to pandas so it will be pretty fast C code. Also, you will need to load the whole DataFrame into memeory anyway, so being faster than linear will not save a lot of time. You could use binary search if you insist however.

Answer (score 0):

For a more efficient search in logarithmic instead of linear time without any extra copies you can run a binary search using [`searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
df.iloc[df['d'].searchsorted(datetime(2000, 1, 4), side='left') - 1]
```

Note that `side='left'` (default) corresponds to `<` (less), and `side=right` corresponds to `<=` (less-equal).

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is intended to retrieve the **values** of the first row before a date then this should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'v': ['a','b','c','d','e']},
                  index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-01',
                                          '2021-01-02',
                                          '2021-01-04',
                                          '2021-01-05',
                                          '2021-01-07']))

            v
2021-01-01  a
2021-01-02  b
2021-01-04  c
2021-01-05  d
2021-01-07  e

df.asof(pd.to_datetime(['2021-01-03']))

            v
2021-01-03  b
```

Note that the index of the row in the returned DF is `'2021-01-03'`.  Also note that `asof()` looks for the first row prior without `NaN`'s - so you'd have to be aware of the logic surrounding that.